# How to close sliding-menu on List Activity Click

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, slide

I have an app that implement sliding menu from **jfeinstein10**. all my apps are not using fragment. so i change the list of fragment into list activity. when i click that list, it start another activity. But the sliding menu didn't close. it still in slide mode. i just want to "when i click item in list activity, it closes slide menu and start an activity." i have tried like this.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    Fragment newContent = null;
    Fragment Intent = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent();
        intent2.setClass(getActivity(), tab.class);
        intent2.putExtra("index", position);
        startActivity(intent2);
        break;
    case 1:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), about.class);
        intent.putExtra("index", position);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case 2:
        Intent intent3 = new Intent();
        intent3.setClass(getActivity(), tab1.class);
        intent3.putExtra("index", position);
        startActivity(intent3);
        break;
    case 3:
        Intent intent4 = new Intent();
        intent4.setClass(getActivity(), latin.class);
        intent4.putExtra("index", position);
        startActivity(intent4);
        break;
    case 4:
        newContent = new ColorFragment(android.R.color.black);
        break;
    }
    if (newContent != null)
        switchFragment(newContent);
    if (Intent != null)
        switchFragment(Intent);

}
```

I know its dumb to use `Fragment Intent = null;` And `If (Intent != Null) switchFragment(Intent);`. I know its just for fragment only, but is there another way to switch it like that? So that when click, the slide menu closed and start the activity. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this kind of code for toggling the state of the Sliding menu

```
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toggle();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: i implement it in my main activity. but its still the same. and i also try it in my menu activity. still same too.

Comment: Can you try to toggle , inside an activity in which you will reach for the menu click.

Comment: so what you want to say is : before the activity start, toggle the slide menu close, and startActivity. is it?

Comment: i try it but it seems its the same. or maybe i dont know how to implement it in the right way. have you tried to make an apps like mine?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ListFragment and your onListItemClick placed there. you can use:

`((MainActivity) this.getActivity()).menu.toggle();`

or:

`((MainActivity) this.getActivity()).getMenu().toggle();`